# Regex: allow comma-separated strings, including characters and non-characters

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I'm finding it difficult to complete this regex.

The following regex checks for the validity of comma-separated strings: `^(\w+)(,\s*\w+)*$`

So, this will match the following comma-separated strings:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^(\w+)(,\s*\w+)*$")
valid_string = "foo, bar, hey,friend, 56, 7, elephant"
pattern.match(valid_string)
```

Then, I can do the same for non-characters, using `^(\W+)(,\s*\W+)*$`, which will match:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^(\W+)(,\s*\W+)*$")
valid_string = "%, $, *, $$"
pattern.match(valid_string)
```

I would like to create a regex which matches strings which include special characters, and hyphens and underscore, e.g.

`foo-bar, hey_friend, 56-8, 7_88, elephant$n`

How could I "combine" `/w` and `/W` to accomplish this?

EDIT:
Here are some examples of invalid strings:

```
invalid1 = "aa, b, c d e"
```

This is invalid, as it is space-separated---it must be comma-separated.

Here's another example:

```
invalid2 = "a, ,b, c, d"
```

This is invalid, as there are two commas; there must only be one.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you provide some examples that _shouldn't_ match?

Comment: Wouldn't "combining" `/w` and `/W` match *everything*?

Comment: @Chris I'll provide some examples in the edit; for example, this shouldn't match, as it is space-separated `a b, c, d`

Comment: @ScottHunter I've tried to edit the question with counterexamples; the string should be comma-separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^\s,]+(?:,\s*[^\s,]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nHkaFR/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\s,]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and commas
- `(?:,\s*[^\s,]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
  - `[^\s,]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and commas
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you for the help and especially for the thorough explanation. I believe this does indeed work---I have listed some counterexamples above.

Comment: Actually, I do have a clarifying question which should help my comprehension: Let's say there are trailing spaces, e.g. `"foo-bar, hey_friend, 56-8, 7_88, elephant$n "`. I think this should be valid....so, in order to change the above regex to allow this, I tried `^[^\s,]+(?:,\s*[^,]+)*$`, but this allows spaces between words

Comment: I think this would work, right? `^[^\s,]+(?:,\s*[^\s,]+)*\s*$` Sorry to ask this---I just want to make sure I'm learning :)

Comment: @EB2127 Just add `\s*` at the start and end of the regex pattern to match leading/trailing whitespace, [`^\s*[^\s,]+(?:,\s*[^\s,]+)*\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/nHkaFR/2).

Answer (score 0):

Is this the regex you need?

```
r"^(\w+[\W_]\w+)(,\s*\w+[\W_]\w+)*$"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This doesn't quite work---I have provided some counterexamples above.